# Setting up Rails Api with Devise JWT for ReactJS Web App in 2019

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jwt

I'm trying to create a new web app using RoR Api and Devise for User authentication and a ReactJS front-end. What I'm looking for are links to an up-to-date github app that uses these things with clean, up-to-date code as well as links to any tutorials that are also up-to-date (as of April 2019).

I'm in the process of using Devise in my app for the api and the issues I am having are essentially different tutorials doing it a bunch of different ways.

Comment: Could also check out doorkeeper to implement authentication for your api.

Answer (score -1):

Always refer to the official docs on GitHub for every gem.
They are always up to date and fairly simple to use.

For **Devise**, refer to [Devise Gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

For **JWT**, refer to [JWT Gem](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt)

For **ReactJS** with Rails, refer to [React-Rails Gem](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails)

I am using the same gems. Visit the links, read them thoroughly and follow the instructions diligently. Always works.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry none of this is what I'm looking for. I'm using Rails as an API not using a React-Rails integration. The documentation on Devise is for Rails, there is a bunch of configuring that needs to happen when using it as an API. I'm using the devise-jwt gem as well so off the mark there. Thanks for trying.

Comment: hey. have you figured this out?